# react-google-login - problems with useGoogleLogout

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing an app with react and react-google-login. It works fine when I login user by useGoogleLogin hook. It writes a lot of cookies (in my app and in https://accounts.google.com), and two sessionStorage items (in https://accounts.google.com). I'm confused that when I logout by useGoogleLogout hook it doesn't remove any cookie (from my page and from https://accounts.google.com) and sessionStorage items stays too. Is it correct way of logout?
I write my authentication code that works fine inside my app but I'm confused why it doesn't clear cookies. It seems to be still signed-in in google.

```
  const { signIn, loaded } = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: handleGoogleSuccessResponse,
    onFailure: handleGoogleFailureResponse,
    isSignedIn: false,
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    cookiePolicy: 'single_host_origin',
  });

  const { signOut } = useGoogleLogout({
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    onLogoutSuccess: handleLogoutSuccess,
    onFailure: handleLogoutFailure,
  });
```

Comment: What's running in `handleLogoutSuccess`?

Comment: I remove a token from the state in handleLogoutSuccess  (so I logout in my react app) and redirect to a home page but the api server doesn't remove any cookies in my browser.